# Ajax show bootstrap alert box 1 time

Tags: javascript, ajax, alert

Now I can make the alert box show, depending on each time I press submit, the alert box keeps increasing. I want it to show only once.

js

```
    $('.form-ajax').on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    var url = form.attr('action');
    var method = form.attr('method');
    var data = form.serialize();
    var callback = form.attr('callback');
    if(typeof callback !=='string'){
        callback = function(response){
            $("#error-box").append('<div class="alert alert-success alert-block">'+'<button 
           type="button" class="close" data-hide-closest=".alert" data- 
           dismiss="alert">×</button>'+'<strong>'+response.message+'</strong>'+'</div>');
            if(typeof response.url ==='string' && response.url!=''){
                window.location.href=response.url;
            }else{
        }
        }
    }
    Helper.ajax (url,method,data,callback)
});
```

Views:

```
      <div id="error-box">
      </div>
```

Comment: `$("#error-box").empty()`? Or use `html()` instead of `append()`

Comment: Yes i use append()

Comment: Right but that adds to existing content...html() replaces existing

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
 Let popup = $(<div id="error-box"></div>);
 //Append popup were you like and when you are done just remove this from dome elements.
 
 $(selector).append(popup);
 //When u r done
 popup.remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a modal.

```
<div class="modal hide" id="myModal" >
  <div class="modal-header">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
    <h3>Error</h3>        
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    Your error message here.
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
  </div>
</div>
```

When you need to show it.

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```